# nested exception is IllegalArgumentException: class AutoProxyRegistrar is not assignable to interface ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Then I build and dismantle my project in several ways, I find this error which has me stuck from one moment to the next started to come out and tells me that I can't import one of the java configuration files (the one for Hibernate).

The project is composed of a .ear, which contains a .jar, a .ejb and the web application.

Please help with the following error:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "ear-1.0.0.ear")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"ear-1.0.0.ear\".\"web-1.0.0.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.creatics.minstituto.config.HibernateConfig]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class org.springframework.context.annotation.AutoProxyRegistrar is not assignable to interface org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.creatics.minstituto.config.HibernateConfig]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class org.springframework.context.annotation.AutoProxyRegistrar is not assignable to interface org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.creatics.minstituto.config.HibernateConfig]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class org.springframework.context.annotation.AutoProxyRegistrar is not assignable to interface org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class org.springframework.context.annotation.AutoProxyRegistrar is not assignable to interface org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar"}}
```

These are the spring and hibernate libraries of the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.4.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
  <version>5.4.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

This is my SpringInitializer:

```
public class SpringInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    // Load database and spring security configuration
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { HibernateConfig.class, SpringSecurityConfig.class };
    }

    // Load spring web configuration
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { SpringWebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

This is my HibernateConfig

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({ "classpath:application.properties", "classpath:hibernate.properties" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScans(value = {
        @ComponentScan("com.creatics.dao"), @ComponentScan("com.creatics.minstituto.dao"),
        @ComponentScan("com.creatics.service"), @ComponentScan("com.creatics.minstituto.service")
})
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Value("${metadata.jndi}")
    private String metadataJNDI;

    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String dialect;

    @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
    private String showSql;

    @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
    private String hbm2ddlAuto;

    @Value("${hibernate.c3p0.min_size}")
    private String c3p0MinSize;

    @Value("${hibernate.c3p0.max_size}")
    private String c3p0MaxSize;

    @Value("${hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment}")
    private String c3p0AcquireIncrement;

    @Value("${hibernate.c3p0.timeout}")
    private String c3p0Timeout;

    @Value("${hibernate.c3p0.max_statements}")
    private String c3p0MaxStatements;

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager() throws Exception {

        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory());

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() throws Exception {

        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionFactoryBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(getDataSource());
        sessionFactoryBuilder.scanPackages("com.creatics.minstituto.model");
        sessionFactoryBuilder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() throws Exception {
        JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        dataSourceLookup.setResourceRef(true);

        return dataSourceLookup.getDataSource(metadataJNDI);
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {

        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.put(DIALECT, dialect);
        properties.put(SHOW_SQL, showSql);
        properties.put(HBM2DDL_AUTO, hbm2ddlAuto);

        properties.put(C3P0_MIN_SIZE, c3p0MinSize);
        properties.put(C3P0_MAX_SIZE, c3p0MaxSize);
        properties.put(C3P0_ACQUIRE_INCREMENT, c3p0AcquireIncrement);
        properties.put(C3P0_TIMEOUT, c3p0Timeout);
        properties.put(C3P0_MAX_STATEMENTS, c3p0MaxStatements);

        return properties;
    }

}
```

this is hibernate.properties:

```
## jndi Properties
metadata.jndi = java:/PostgresDS/database

## Hibernate Properties
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate

#C3P0 properties
hibernate.c3p0.min_size=5
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=20
hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment=1
hibernate.c3p0.timeout=1800
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=150
```